# Word to describe an insubstantial act or detail that signals an a level of care / quality that is less obvious or unseen

Tags: single-word-requests

I swear I ran across a specific word for this recently, I believe in the context of user design, but I cannot for the life of me think what it is now.

An example might be the triangle fold on the toilet paper in a hotel bathroom, which in itself is not really important, but signals that the bathroom was likely cleaned.

It's not "meticulous" (which came up a lot as I was googling for such a word).

Answer (score 2):

**touch** (n.)

> A detail or feature, typically one that gives something a distinctive
> character.
>
> *the film's most inventive touch* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/touch)

> An effective and subtle detail
>
> *applies the finishing touches to the story* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/touch)

> A touch is a detail which is added to something to improve it.
>
> *They called the event "a tribute to heroes," which was a nice touch.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/touch)

---

> His handwriting and math diagrams show great care. He spent time doing
> them well, adding **touches** of artistic flair. All his life George
> loved beauty in things great and small; he loved careful details and
> planning. [B. Miller; *George Washington for Kids*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/George_Washington_for_Kids/fxINBnD8IKAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=small%20touches%20that%20showed%20great%20care&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> Business cards. Go that extra mile and impress your Dutch colleagues
> by getting a Dutch translation of all pertinent documents, including
> your business card. It is not required, but a nice **touch**. [Larry
> Kulchawik; *Trade Shows from One Country to the Next*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trade_Shows_From_One_Country_To_The_Next/YzBjCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=a%20nice%20touch%20that%20showed&pg=PT142&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

Comment: CD's also worth quoting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Collins? (Added)

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary. But Collins gives the same sense.

Answer (score 0):

A **scintilla** is defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scintilla) thus:

> *Scintilla* comes directly from Latin, where it carries the meaning of
> "spark" – that is, a bright flash such as you might see from a burning
> ember. In English, however, our use of "scintilla" is restricted to
> the figurative sense of "spark" – a hint or trace of something that
> barely suggests its presence.

But as [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/scintilla) adds, it is usually used in negative statements (negative grammatically and/or in flavour). It is also in a literary etc register.

[Definitions.USLegal.com](https://definitions.uslegal.com/s/scintilla-of-evidence/) shows the term being used in a positive (sign of possible underlying quality / genuineness) sense:

> The scintilla evidence rule states that if there is so much as “a mere
> gleam, glimmer, spark, the least particle or the smallest trace of
> evidence” supporting an inference, then the issue must be submitted to
> the jury.” [Hayes v. Luckey, 33 F. Supp. 2d 987 (N.D. Ala. 1997)]

And [NYTimes_2021](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/17/sports/soccer/world-cup-qualifying-norway.html) has:

> There was, then, still a scintilla of hope. Norway needed to beat the
> Netherlands, in Rotterdam, to have a chance of qualifying
> automatically for its first World Cup since 1998, and its first major
> tournament since 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Something specific describing user design regarding care might be,

***Token*** - "A token of his gratitude."

[Token - Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/token)